# What would the Ubuntu Server be used for?

Tags: server

I don't truly understand what i would use that for and i am wondering, i have script coded a gaming server for Garry's Mod and i was wondering what this server would be used for ?

Comment: Ubuntu server is an operating system designed to run 24/7. If garry's mod has a server application and if you want to run it on a server then Ubuntu server would work fine, but a normal desktop install would probably work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Server is an operating system meant for dedicated servers, computers that are used for nothing but being a server. Ubuntu Server would be pretty good for running a Garry's Mod server (I've done it!). However, I like Debian more for servers because of the increased stability and easier upgrades. Ubuntu Server does not come with a desktop environment, so unless you consider yourself an advanced user and know how to do everything from the terminal (which includes configuring your network, which I find pretty difficult), you might want to get a lightweight Ubuntu distro and run your Garry's Mod server off that. If you want a very light GUI so your Garry's Mod server will perform better, I recommend getting the latest LTS release of Lubuntu. If you know how to use Debian (which is very similar), you may want to get Debian wheezy with LXDE. You can remove the desktop manager (usually LightDM) so that when your computer starts up you're at a shell, and you can type `startx` to access LXDE only when you need it. You know, to save resources and stuff when you don't need a desktop environment. You can start it up only when you need to change something that would be hard from the terminal. Ubuntu Server has a few kernel tweaks to it that makes it perform better than Ubuntu Desktop when running server applications. However, if you're running a Garry's Mod server which requires a lot of processing power and a little less focus on networking, I don't think you'll notice much of a difference.

Comment: icewm or fluxbox are even more lightweight than lxde

Comment: @mchid I suppose so, but there is no official Ubuntu flavor that comes with those. If Bradley Henry knows how to install either of those, I would encourage it. If he installs an unofficial Ubuntu flavor that comes with either of those, he will not be allowed to ask for support on Ask Ubuntu or Stack Exchange as they are unofficial. Nethertheless, IceWM and Fluxbox are good choices.

Comment: You're right, I was talking about debian wheezy and forgot to mention but http://unix.stackexchange.com is still and option as well